# Django Admin, SELECT по полям

Tags: python, django

Есть модуль `UserTask` в которой есть очень тяжелые поля и они тормозят запрос, как можно убрать их из запроса для Django Admin.

Они не выводятся на страницу, но Django использует примерно такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM UserTask;
```

А нужно:

```
SELECT id, name, is_user FROM UserTask;
```

P.S. Нужно убрать их именно в админке, вот регистрация модели:

```
class UserTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('id', 'name')
    list_display = ('id', 'name')    


admin.site.register(UserTask, UserTaskAdmin)
```

кривой перевод на [английский](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501983/django-admin-select-by-fields)

Comment: values или values_list https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/querysets.html#values

Comment: @andreymal это понятно, но как это использовать при регистрации модули в админке?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете переопределить `get_queryset()` и использовать [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) метод:

```
class UserTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('id', 'name')
    list_display = ('id', 'name') 

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.only('id', 'name')
```

> Немного изменил оригинал, там использовался `UserTask.objects.only('id', 'name')`, за места `self.model.objects.only('id', 'name')`, что ограничивало повторное использования кода с другими моделями.

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51502062/6623896) от [@neverwalkaloner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641249/neverwalkaloner).